# How to combine two arrays in a php shuffle

Tags: php, shuffle

I am attempting to create a shuffle feature to pair people up for a gift exchange. I created the basic shell of it and am not really sure where to go from here. I am getting the output to shuffle the data, however I am wanting to combine both the `array_give` and `array_receive` variables so that it would output something along the line of:

Paul & Becky are giving to Keith & Jackie.

I am unsure how to combine this, though. The `array_give` variable does not need shuffled, just the `array_receive` variable does.

Also is there a way to ensure the results do not display as the following?

Paul & Becky are giving to Paul & Becky

Here is my code. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
<button type="button" id="shuffle">Create Exchange</button>
<div id="name-output"></div>
```

JS

```
$('#shuffle').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/name-selection.php',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#name-output').html(data);
            },
            complete:function(){

            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + '|' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    })
```

PHP

```
$array_give = array('Paul & Becky', 'Keith & Jackie', 'Dave & Lauren', 'Ashley & Jeric', 'Rob & Savannah');
$array_receive = array('Paul & Becky', 'Keith & Jackie', 'Dave & Lauren', 'Ashley & Jeric', 'Rob & Savannah');

shuffle($array_receive);

foreach( $array_receive as $receiving) {
    echo $receiving . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function to combine to arrays is called `array_combine`. You can read about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php), and use it like this:

```
<?php
function checkSame ($a, $b) {
  foreach (array_combine($a,$b) as $key => $value)
    if ($key===$value) return true;
  return false;
}

$array_give = array('Paul & Becky', 'Keith & Jackie', 'Dave & Lauren', 'Ashley & Jeric', 'Rob & Savannah');
$array_receive = array('Paul & Becky', 'Keith & Jackie', 'Dave & Lauren', 'Ashley & Jeric', 'Rob & Savannah');

while (checkSame($array_give, $array_receive)) shuffle($array_receive);

foreach( array_combine($array_give, $array_receive) as $give => $receiving) 
{
  echo $give. " give to ".$receiving . "<br>";
}
```

My idea for preventing self gifts, is to simply keep on shuffling the array until nobody is assigned to themselves. In theory this could run forever, but I think for most practical uses it will stop fairly quickly.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at the array_combine function, but couldn't figure it out. Do you know if there is anyway I can display each result one by one with a timer of sorts?

Comment: A simple [sleep(5);](http://php.net/manual/de/function.sleep.php) (5 seconds) after each echo should do it.

Comment: I just tried your recommendation. It doesn't display a result after 25 seconds (all the results ran) and then it shows a 0 after each one.

Comment: Strange. The 0 probably means that sleep failed and returned false. But I don't know why it gets printed. Maybe you can try usleep with a bigger number.

Answer (score 2):

As the array is essentially the same, you only need one array.

You can then pop/pick out each element on each iteration, this will stop self gifting and allow for a check that someone wont receive a gift, bah humbug!

```
<?php
$array_give = array('Paul & Becky', 'Keith & Jackie', 'Dave & Lauren', 'Ashley & Jeric', 'Rob & Savannah');

shuffle($array_give);

$i = 0;
while ($give = array_pop($array_give)) {
    echo $give;
    if ($i % 2 != 0) {
        echo "<br>".PHP_EOL;
    } elseif (count($array_give) == 0) {
        echo ' is getting zilch! ';
        break;
    } else {
        echo ' are giving to ';
    }
    $i++;
}
```

.

```
Rob & Savannah are giving to Ashley & Jeric<br>
Dave & Lauren are giving to Keith & Jackie<br>
Paul & Becky is getting zilch!
```

https://3v4l.org/KtJ47